Docker with mongodb replicaset on windows powershell
Hello I am trying to dockerize my nodeJS server with docker and mongodb replica.
the following is my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: mongo1
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/data/mongodb-keyfile"]
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mongo1_data:/data/db
      - ./mongodb-keyfile:/data/mongodb-keyfile:ro

  mongo2:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: mongo2
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/data/mongodb-keyfile"]
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mongo2_data:/data/db
      - ./mongodb-keyfile:/data/mongodb-keyfile:ro

  mongo3:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: mongo3
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/data/mongodb-keyfile"]
    ports:
      - 27019:27017
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mongo3_data:/data/db
      - ./mongodb-keyfile:/data/mongodb-keyfile:ro

volumes:
  mongo1_data:
  mongo2_data:
  mongo3_data:

my mongoDB uri :
mongodb://mongo1:27017/?replicaSet=myReplicaSet

tried
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017,127.0.0.1:27018,127.0.0.1:27019/?replicaSet=myReplicaSet

as well
now if I try to npm run dev, my server crashes with error :

MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo1

also, if I try to run docker compose up I have the following issue
time="2024-08-25T20:23:37+03:00" level=warning msg="The \"BHSOL\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2024-08-25T20:23:37+03:00" level=warning msg="The \"BHSOL\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2024-08-25T20:23:37+03:00" level=warning msg="The \"BHSOL\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
[+] Running 0/0
 - Container mongo2  Creating                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 - Container mongo1  Creating                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 - Container mongo3  Creating                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
Error response from daemon: Access is denied.

Edit:
I have managed to fix it and run the docker compose up which runs correctly. the issue was with the powershell.
the new docker-compose.yml file is this one:
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo1
    hostname: mongo1
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME: "rs0"
  
  mongo2:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo2
    hostname: mongo2
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME: "rs0"

  mongo3:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo3
    hostname: mongo3
    ports:
      - 27019:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME: "rs0"

but,
now I can't connect to mongoDB compass. I don't have any error it just tries to connect for too long and can't connect.
I have tried
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017,127.0.0.1:27018,127.0.0.1:27019/?replicaSet=myReplicaSet

mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/?replicaSet=myReplicaSet

mongodb://mongo1:27017/?replicaSet=myReplicaSet

mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27018,mongo3:27019/?replicaSet=myReplicaSet

none of them worked

did you initialize replica set after constiner started??

Yes I did initialize

After starting the docker containers, you have to connect to one of the servers though MongoSH (MongoDB shell) and run the rs.initiate() command, and then add the other servers with rs.add("hostname").
Note that you cannot connect to the replica set from outside the docker network because the hostnames mongo1, mongo2 and mongo3 would not resolve. You need to run "mongosh" from within the docker network with something like this: "docker exec -it mongo1 mongosh mongodb://mongo1,mongo2,mongo3/?replicaSet=rs"
This YouTube video from last year demonstrates what I have explained above:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ckn1jZA98Zk
Also, MongoDB version 4.4 has reached end-of-life (See: https://www.mongodb.com/legal/support-policy/lifecycles ). Use a more recent version - version 7.0 is the latest Generally Available release, with version 8.0 expected to be released in the near future.
